Why is the parent view's onDisappear() automatically invoked by the SwiftUI framework?
In the code below, if I click a row, Hello, in the List, the List's onDisappear() is invoked, as indicated by the trace, onDisappear called!. Is this expected?
I have some logic that needs to be executed when the List view is dismissed by an explicit action from the users. Thus, such an auto-invocation of onDisappear() would be problematic for me, if not accounted for.
Is it possible to prevent the framework from auto-invoking onDisappear for the parent view?

import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct DebugOnDisappear: View {
    var body: some View {
        UnexpectedOnDisappear()
            .onDisappear() {
                print("onDisappear called!")
            }
    }
    
    struct UnexpectedOnDisappear: View {
        @Query private var sbEntries: [SafeBoxEntryModel] = []
        
        var body: some View {
            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach (sbEntries) { sbEntry in
                        NavigationLink("Hello") {Text("Hello")}
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


Screenshot for listing

Screenshot for trace output


I think it's expected? NavigationLink makes you navigate to another view, that is, the current view (that hosts the link) is destroyed.

I believe the system needs to remember (keep track of) the parent view because users can navigate back. Thus, if the dismissal is expected for a purpose of optimization, it should not be "exposed" (such as "freed up internally" only and re-rendered why needed).

I'm pretty sure views don't get stored nor cached, that's just their state. Views are structs in SwiftUI, that is, value types. The state is reassociated to the View when recreated using its type and position in the views hierarchy (take my words at face value, that's just how I rememeber it).

I think this behavior of auto-destruction of the parent view is undesirable because the application's logic in onDisappear() would be invoked unnecessarily by the framework, i.e., the logic is intended to respond to user's explicit actions in the child view only.

This is an XY problem. You cannot stop SwiftUI from doing this. Can you explain what your actual situation is (show a [mcve]) so we can suggest ways you can work around this?

I've run into the problem of infinite loop caused by dismiss() (in swiftui) a number of times. This problem has been reported by many people, and I believe, it has not been fixed. When I encounter the behavior of auto-invocation of onDisappear(), I find that questionable (as I've described above). As a result, I wanted to ask whether this is a known problem (due to some random combination/sequence of calls/apis), or an expected behavior.
